# seteo de clase al refrescar el sitio reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, component

tengo una función para setear el idioma cuando cambio desde el selector de mi sitio, estoy tratando de usar componentDidMount y setState para hacer que ese seteo de clase se haga cuando se carga por primera vez, (cuando se hace refresh en el sitio), pero me tira error todo el rato.

```
languagesList() {
    return [
      { name: 'English', value: 'en', id: 1 },
      { name: 'French (Français)', value: 'fr', id: 4 },
      { name: 'German (Deutsch)', value: 'de', id: 5 },
      { name: 'Indonesian (Bahasa Indonesia)', value: 'id', id: 6 },
      { name: 'Italian (Italiano)', value: 'it', id: 7 },
      { name: 'Japanese (日本語)', value: 'ja', id: 8 },
      { name: 'Korean (한국어)', value: 'ko', id: 9 },
      { name: 'Polish (Polski)', value: 'pl', id: 11 },
      { name: 'Portuguese (Português)', value: 'br', id: 2 },
      { name: 'Russian (Русский)', value: 'ru', id: 12 },
      { name: 'Simplified Chinese (简体中文)', value: 'cn', id: 3 },
      { name: 'Spanish (Español Latino)', value: 'ex', id: 10 },
      { name: 'Spanish (Español)', value: 'es', id: 13 },
      { name: 'Thai (ไทย)', value: 'th', id: 15 },
      { name: 'Traditional Chinese (繁體中文)', value: 'tw', id: 14 },
      { name: 'Turkish (Türkçe)', value: 'tr', id: 16 },
      { name: 'Vietnamese (Tiếng Việt)', value: 'vi', id: 17 },
    ]
  }

  handleChange(data) {
   
    document.getElementById('root').classList.remove(this.props.lang)
    document.getElementById('root').classList.add(data.value)

    this.props.fetchSetLanguage(data.id)
    const { value, name } = data
    this.setState({
      languages: name,
      open: false,
    })
    localStorage.setItem('langObj', JSON.stringify(data))
    this.props.setLanguages(value)

    componentDidMount() {
      this.languagesList();
    }
  }
```

[image: este es el error que me aparece]

Comment: Creo que sería increíblemente útil que compartas tu error.

Comment: Uhm por cierto, `componentDidMount` se utiliza en el scope de tu clase, *creo* que no puedes meterlo en otra función. Al menos nunca había visto eso, *creo* es un método de la misma clase de componente de React de donde heredas con `extend`

Comment: si he añadido el error que me sale @FranAcuna

Comment: Pareciera ser que el problema si es dónde pusiste el `componentDidMount` te recomiendo sacarlo de ahí y ponerlo dentro de tu clase (Componente de React).

Comment: vale, gracias ahora ya no tengo el error, pero si sigo teniendo el mismo problema que planteo al principio, que el seteo de clase se haga cuando la página se refresca

Comment: Con gusto, si compartes todo el código de tu componente creo que sería más facil ayudarte.

Answer (score 0):

Visto que ya cambiaste de posición el `componentDidMount()` al Scope de la clase, piensa que debes conseguir un flujo de información.
Cargas un lenguaje inicial, lo guardas en localStorage. Luego si Recargas la página, lo primero que debes hacer es:

En el constructor, cargar lo que hay en el localStorage (el lenguajes guardado) y si es que hay algo guardado, si no hay nada, entonces debes aplicar un idioma por default.

Cuando recargas la página los state desaparecen, por lo que la única forma de manetenerlos es leerlos siempre del localStorage en la carga inicial de datos (de la clase o del componente que sea al cargarse).

Comment: Gracias, por las respuestas. Pero descurbrí que el problema no lo tenía en esta parte de mi componente.